# Overwriting existing object properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, overwrite

I am having trouble with two small blocks of code and understanding why one works and one doesn't.

I have an array of 'tasks'.
When a user updates a task, I need to update the AuditLog, to show the update.
I have two blocks of code, first one works, second one doesn't.

1st block - when I view the updated task, it shows the updated log.

2nd block - when I view the updated task, the log is not updated.

I suspect that it is something to do with the way I am referencing, assigning things.

This block correctly updates the "task" and viewing it shows the updated "audit log".

```
//update task with server response 'a'
this.updateTask(task).subscribe(a => {
  let updatedTask = initializeTask(a);
  task.auditLog = updatedTask.auditLog;
});
```

Then I thought I could simplify the code a bit...
but when using this block, when I view the task, it does not show the updated log.
(I should mention that printing 'intializeTask(a)' works correctly and prints the updated log values, so it's not to do with that).

```
//update task with server response 'a'
this.updateTask(task).subscribe(a => {
  task = initializeTask(a);
});
```

I feel like I may be missing something fundamental in the way JavaScript references/assigns variables etc. Perhaps someone can shed some light on it.

Thanks in advance!

PS: initializeTask simply ensures that nothing is left undefined and that dates are formatted correctly:

```js
export function initializeTask(t): Task {
    t.subject = t.subject || '';
    t.startTime = initDate(t.startTime);
    t.state = t.state || 'Published';
    t.createdBy = t.createdBy || '';
    if (t.auditLog) {
        t.auditLog.forEach(d => {
            d.createdOn = initDate(d.createdOn);
        });
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: A reproducible will be helpful for others to check, from the limited code you pasted I don't see why it does not work.

Comment: What does `initializeTask()` do?

Comment: I shall endeavour to create a reproducible. Interesting to know that there isn't an obvious error with the above. Thanks.

initializeTask ensures that nothing is undefined at that the dates are formatted correctly (not 1970), I have added above.

Comment: "when I view the task, it does not show the updated log"  How are you viewing the task?  If you are holding onto a reference to the original task (in a different variable or something), then it will not be updated.  But this is not a [mcve] because there's not enough of it to reproduce anything.  Ideally you would give code that could be dropped into a standalone IDE to demonstrate the issue; less ideally but still acceptable is a link to a properly-configured web IDE project that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please show us where `task` is defined and where you show its contents. Apparently your code that displays the log does have a reference to the object you are mutating, not to the variable that you are overwriting.